# Extending shadowbuilder has compile error in Monodroid

Tags: xamarin.android

I want to extend the ShadowBuilder in order to change the canvas size when dragged. However, i'm not able to compile it because of the compile error below.

Here's the code to my ShadowBuilder

```
public class TileShadow : View.DragShadowBuilder
{
    //private Drawable mShadow;

    public TileShadow()
    {
    }

    public TileShadow(View view)
        : base(view)
    {
    }

    protected TileShadow(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
    }

    public override void OnDrawShadow(Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.Scale(1.8f, 1.8f);
        base.OnDrawShadow(canvas);
        //mShadow.Draw(canvas);
        //View.Draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Error   25   cannot find symbol
symbol  : class DragShadowBuilder
location: class android.view.View
    extends android.view.View.DragShadowBuilder

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What API level are you targeting? `DragShadowBuilder` is available in Level 11 onwards.

I tested your code on Mono for Android 4.2.6 targeting API Level 12 (with Minimum Level Android 3.1) and it compiled without an issue and deployed to the emulator.

Have you tried to Clean/Rebuild the Solution?

Have you tried creating a new Project from scratch and implementing this class to see if the issue is isolated to your existing Solution?

Also check what your ACW looks like in the obj\debug\android\src\wordshuffle\android\shadowbuilders\ folder.

Mine looked like this

```
package androidapplication1;


public class TileShadow
    extends android.view.View.DragShadowBuilder
    implements
        mono.android.IGCUserPeer
    {
    static final String __md_methods;
    static {
        __md_methods = 
            "n_onDrawShadow:(Landroid/graphics/Canvas;)V:GetOnDrawShadow_Landroid_graphics_Canvas_Handler\n" +
            "";
        mono.android.Runtime.register ("AndroidApplication1.TileShadow, AndroidApplication1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null", TileShadow.class, __md_methods);
    }


    public TileShadow (android.view.View p0)
    {
        super (p0);
        if (getClass () == TileShadow.class)
            mono.android.TypeManager.Activate ("AndroidApplication1.TileShadow, AndroidApplication1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null", "Android.Views.View, Mono.Android, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c4c4237547e4b6cd", this, new java.lang.Object[] { p0 });
    }


    public TileShadow ()
    {
        super ();
        if (getClass () == TileShadow.class)
            mono.android.TypeManager.Activate ("AndroidApplication1.TileShadow, AndroidApplication1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null", "", this, new java.lang.Object[] {  });
    }


    public void onDrawShadow (android.graphics.Canvas p0)
    {
        n_onDrawShadow (p0);
    }

    private native void n_onDrawShadow (android.graphics.Canvas p0);

    java.util.ArrayList refList;
    public void monodroidAddReference (java.lang.Object obj)
    {
        if (refList == null)
            refList = new java.util.ArrayList ();
        refList.add (obj);
    }

    public void monodroidClearReferences ()
    {
        if (refList != null)
            refList.clear ();
    }
}
```

Comment: hi alexw, thank you. it worked now. I'm targeting api 8 and didnt compile. change to API 12 now. Does this mean i would not be able to support mobile devices using API 8?

Comment: Yes that is correct. If you wish to target prior devices you would have to check the version at run-time and only use this class if the version is API Level 11 or higher. Please see this question for more info on how to do that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272397/android-backward-compatibility-but-still-utilise-latest-api-features