# Android Api level 4 compatibility error

Tags: android, compatibility, android-support-library

I'm using supportv4 compatibility library, the target Api level of my app is 17, and i want to make it work even in Api level 4.
When i run my app i have this error only in api level 4 :

```
03-11 16:16:01.412: E/dalvikvm(302): Could not find method android.view.Display.getSize, referenced from method com.meher.tools.menulauncher.common.MyApplicationContext.setScreenDimensions
03-11 16:16:01.412: W/dalvikvm(302): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3065: Landroid/view/Display;.getSize (Landroid/graphics/Point;)V
03-11 16:16:01.412: W/dalvikvm(302): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x6e at 0x0018
03-11 16:16:01.412: W/dalvikvm(302): VFY:  rejected Lcom/meher/tools/menulauncher/common/MyApplicationContext;.setScreenDimensions (Landroid/view/Display;)V
03-11 16:16:01.412: W/dalvikvm(302): Verifier rejected class Lcom/meher/tools/menulauncher/common/MyApplicationContext;
03-11 16:16:01.422: D/AndroidRuntime(302): Shutting down VM
03-11 16:16:01.422: W/dalvikvm(302): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001aa28)
03-11 16:16:01.422: E/AndroidRuntime(302): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
03-11 16:16:01.422: E/AndroidRuntime(302): java.lang.VerifyError: com.meher.tools.menulauncher.common.MyApplicationContext
03-11 16:16:01.422: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at com.meher.tools.menulauncher.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:79)
03-11 16:16:01.422: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
03-11 16:16:01.422: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
03-11 16:16:01.422: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
03-11 16:16:01.422: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:116)
03-11 16:16:01.422: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
03-11 16:16:01.422: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-11 16:16:01.422: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-11 16:16:01.422: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
03-11 16:16:01.422: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-11 16:16:01.422: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-11 16:16:01.422: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
03-11 16:16:01.422: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
03-11 16:16:01.422: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-11 16:16:01.422: I/dalvikvm(302): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
03-11 16:16:01.422: E/dalvikvm(302): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

This is the code raising the error :

**MainActivity.java :**

```
// Init application context
        myApplicationContext = new MyApplicationContext(this,
                getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay());
```

**MyApplicationContext.java :**

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void setScreenDimensions(Display display) {
        Point size = new Point();
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 13) {
            this.screenWidth = display.getWidth();
            this.screenHeight = display.getHeight();
        } else {
            try {
                display.getSize(size);
                this.screenWidth = size.x;
                this.screenHeight = size.y;
            } catch (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError ignore) { // Older device
                this.screenWidth = display.getWidth();
                this.screenHeight = display.getHeight();
            }
        }
    }
```

**AndroidManifest.mf :**

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="4"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API Level 4 does a full check of every method used in the class to make sure it exists, as noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12290957/1676363). Therefore you can either:

- encapsulate all new API calls in separate classes (which, because they aren't loaded in your v4 runtime due to conditional logic, are never greedily checked)
- move your minimum SDK to v7 (Android 2.1) and lose the [0.2%](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) of the Android population still using v4.

Comment: Thank you very much for this information, i noticed that because the error is raised even before code is reached in the moment when the VM load the class ! i think i will make it compatible only for api level 10 or more if there is only 0.2% of population to lose !

Comment: Your logic here (of conditionally executing new APIs based on the SDK_INT) will work on any v7+ device.

Note that API v10+ apps reach 90.2% of the current Android population (per that same dashboard).

Comment: Yes i meaned API level 7, i tested my app in Android 2.1 Emulator it works perfectly, thank you again !